# finding "pi" using Monte Carlo's rand() method

Tags: c++

i'm trying to find the actual accuracy after inputting the given accuracy to get "pi" value using Monte Carlo's random method. Supposedly the answer for actual accuracy should be as close to the given accuracy. But I kept on getting around 0.7 for my actual accuracy when I run the program which is not close to the given accuracy at all. I tried to see what's my "pi" value and it seems to converge at around 3.11-3.12....really need your help..here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

using namespace std;

void values(float *pi, int *P, int *Q)
{
    float x(0), y(0);
    x = (rand()%100)/99.0;
    y = (rand()%100)/99.0;
    if(sqrt((x*x)+(y*y))<=1)
    {
        (*P)++;
    }
    (*Q)++;
    *pi = 4.0*(*P)/(*Q);
}

float get_pi(float required_accuracy)
{
    int D(0), N(0);
    float pi_estimate(0), x(0), y(0), temp(0);
    while(N<=100)
    {
        values(&pi_estimate,&D,&N);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if(4./(N+1.)<((required_accuracy*0.01)*(pi_estimate)))
        {
            cout<<pi_estimate<<endl;
            return (pi_estimate);
        }
        values(&pi_estimate,&D,&N);
    }
}

int main()
{
    for(float a=0.1;a>=1.e-14;a/=10.)
    {
        cout<<"Actual accuracy : "<<(fabs(get_pi(a) - M_PI)/(M_PI))*100.<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're generating random coordinates on a 100x100 grid by using `(rand() % 100) / 99.0`. That pretty much guarantees that you'll get a wrong answer. `(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX` is a better way to get a random number in [0,1].

Comment: i'll try to ask the lecturer whether the answers are acceptable since it's dealing with random generator concept...ty so much..^^

Answer (score 2):

I think you should increase accuracy of these numbers:

```
x = (rand()%100)/99.0;
y = (rand()%100)/99.0;
```

by writing something like

```
x = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
y = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it help if you have used `double` instead of `float`?

Comment: others are correct, unless you increase the number of samples by increasing that grid size inside `values()` it won't converge. float will do it just fine.